# How to use Nominatim API through PHP

Tags: php, json, geocoding, nominatim

It's a more general version of the topic [How to use Nominatim API through PHP to retrieve latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423767/how-to-use-nominatim-api-through-php-to-retrieve-latitude-and-longitude) which was asked in June 2017.

Currently, I just get an **empty response**.

Is it still possible to use the API with PHP `file_get_contents`?

---

**Example API call**

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=grindelwald&countryCodes=CH&addressdetails=1&format=json

Comment: Have you considered the cURL extension

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please add a comment to clarify this, thank you

Comment: The given example URL works fine in my browser, and doesn't appear to require any additional credentials - so yes, in theory it should work fine with `file_get_contents`. Whether the API might have any additional restrictions, or requires certain request characteristics to be fulfilled (like, a `User-Agent` header being set at least), can't be told form the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site required the `User-Agent` header

```
$url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=grindelwald&countryCodes=CH&addressdetails=1&format=json';
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'Simon Ferndriger',
    ],
];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I recommend using the [guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) package for HTTP requests.